# Why is my radio circuit working with other arduinos but not the Pro Minis?

Tags: serial

I have some Arduino Pro Minis. I have both the 3.3V/8MHz and 5V/16MHz versions. I'm trying to get them to work with the [nRF24L01 RF modules](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Nrf24L01-2.4GHz-HowTo).

I've lightly modified some example code from the RF24 library, and gotten it working with an Arduino Micro and Nano. Basically, I just send an increasing integer from one to the other, and the receiving one displays on an LCD the latest number it received, which lets me know if a transmitter is working.

So that all works. Now I'm trying to use a Pro Mini (tried both 3.3V and 5V versions) to transmit instead of the Nano I was using before. The regulator is a 3.3V LDO. The battery is supplying that LDO and the RAW pin of the Pro Mini with ~8.5V, which should be good. Measuring the voltage out of the LDO gives 3.3V.

I looked at the pinout of the Pro Mini, and I believe I've hooked up the module to the correct MOSI/MISO/SCK pins, as well as pins 7 and 8 for the module's CE and CSN pins.

Buuut... it's not working. Nothing is appearing on the LCD. I know the nRF and its header thing work fine, because I can pop the exact one into the circuit with the Nano that works.

Even more strangely, I'm pretty sure the Pro Minis are getting programmed successfully. I can upload the Blink example to them, and that works. I'm using an Adafruit FTDI friend to upload, and that appears to be working (compiles, uploads, etc without error).

[Here's the code I'm using for the transmitter](http://pastebin.com/hcN6Rds7), it's pretty simple. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Let me know if there's anything I forgot to include.

edit: It won't let me include more than two links because of my low rep, so I can't include images of my ciruit/wiring. But I'll manually write it out here:

The numbering here is with respect to the pins in the nRF link above.

```
nRF module pin           Arduino Pro Mini Pin
1 (GND)           GND rail (not on Arduino)
2 (VCC)           3.3V rail (from external regulator)
3 (CE)           Digital pin 7
4 (CSN)           Digital pin 8
5 (SCK)           Digital pin 13
6 (MOSI)           Digital pin 11
7 (MISO)           Digital pin 12
8 (IRQ)           Not connected to anything
```

Comment: Can you also show us the wiring diagram / schematic?

Comment: @josecanuc ahh I originally included it in my OP but it didn't let me include more than two links... I'm following the stuff in the 1st link, but I'll edit it explicitly in my OP, thank you.

Comment: @josecanuc I've edited it, let me try including an image here though, of my wiring: http://i.imgur.com/c7TF64M.jpg